# Loading indicator until tableView loads

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I am using Parse to load some data for title , http req for ImageView and  ratingView. I also have a segment control view with 2 options.
I put an indicator where the image is presented , but when I scroll down
or when I press another segment(different movies) I get for 1-2 seconds the previous image , ratingView , titles and they change after this instantly. And obviously not all together. Can I somehow sync the changes or give an indicator 'waiting to load' until everything loads ?

```
func segmentView(segmentView: SMSegmentView, didSelectSegmentAtIndex index: Int) {
        self.currentSegmentSelected = index
        loadData().findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { [weak self] objects, error in
            if error == nil {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self?.loadObjects()
                })}
            }
    }
```

queryForTable(Parse)

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"Movies")
        if(objects?.count == 0)
        {
            query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
        }
        if self.currentSegmentSelected == 0 {
            query.whereKey("genres", containsString: "Adventure")
        }
        else if currentSegmentSelected == 1 {
            query.whereKey("genres", containsString: "Comedy")
        }
        return query
    }
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
        let cellIdentifier:String = "cell"
        var cell:TableCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? TableCell
        if(cell == nil) {
            cell = TableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }

 //???      indicator.startAnimating()
 //???       indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    if let pfObject = object {

        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("averageStars", withParameters: ["movieId":pfObject["movieId"]]) {
            (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let rating = response as! Float? {
            cell?.rating.rating = rating
            }}

        if let movieId = pfObject["movieId"] as? Int {
            if RecommendedSet.ratings[movieId] == nil {
                cell?.userRating.rating = 0
            } else {
               cell?.userRating.rating = RecommendedSet.ratings[movieId]!
            }
        }

        cell?.title?.text = pfObject["title"] as? String

        if let Id = pfObject["tmdbId"] as? Int {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, timdb , parameters: ["api_key": APIkey])
            .responseJSON { response in
                if let JSON...
                let imgData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL)!                   
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    cell?.posterView?.image = UIImage(data: imgData)
             //???  self.indicator.stopAnimating()
             //??? self.indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                                    })
                }}}}}}}
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can. You are most of the way there already. But first you need to fix the way you are dealing with the asynchronous nature of data loading; right now you're doing wrong. When the data arrives, don't change the cell directly; put the new data into the _model_ and _reload_ the cell.

Comment: You mean change call cell.poster,cell.title etc all together ? and then self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)  ??

Comment: No, absolutely not. Model-view-controller. The cell is view. The cell should be configured in `cellForRow` from some model object. Change the model and then reload the row that `cellForRow` is called again and reconfigures the cell. You can use Parse to fetch data asynchronously, but that data needs to be stored in some model object that can be queried instantly, since you never know when `cellForRow` will be called, and when it is called, you must return a cell _immediately_.

Comment: So the best way is to avoid pfquerytable , as it provides the model inside cellforrow.

Comment: I created a model: Movies class , then in viewdidappear I query Parse and stored into my model the data from there , and also calling async for the images. then into cellForRow I use my model. I am on the right track ?

Comment: I am getting some trouble with the images. I cant give the cellForRow instant UIImage from http request , and I cant wait for 1000 (the size of the table) to load before showing anything. So I guess I have to call Http request for Images inside cellFowRow to make it work and just give the movieId to the model

Comment: Not sure what you have now, but you have to supply a placeholder image if you have none and then ask for one (and reload later when you _do_ have one and the model has changed). This code illustrates the technique, though it does not use Parse: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyTableViewController.swift